# Calculating $P(X+Y=0)$ for independent random variables (Problem in Durrett)

Tags: probability-theory

Exercise 2.1.8 in Durrett's Probability: Theory and Examples is the following:

> Show that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent with distributions $\mu$ and
>   $\nu$, then $$P(X+Y=0) = \sum_y \mu(\{-y\})\nu(\{y\}).$$

If I define $h(x,y) = \chi_{x=-y}$, then using Fubini and the change of variables formula, I get

$$P(X+Y=0) = Eh(X,Y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} h\,d(\mu\times \nu) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x,y)\,\mu(dx)\nu(dy)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mu(\{-y\})\,\nu(dy).$$

How do I get to the final sum form? What bothers me here is that the sum in the problem description seems to be over an uncountable set, so is this again an example of Durrett using strange notation that is not defined anywhere in the book and the integral that I've computed above means the same?

Comment: Do $X$ and $Y$ take values in $\mathbb{R}$ are on $\mathbb{Q}$ or some other countable set?

Comment: Problem is copied verbatim from the book.

Comment: Then I suspect that somewhere before the problem it is stated in the book that it is assumed that $X$ and $Y$ take values in an countable set. And if that the case, we have that summation is nothing more than integration when we are dealing with a countable set.

Comment: Nope, the book doesn't assume anything about countable sets. I guess this is one more case of undefined notation then. The book seems to be riddled with them...

Comment: Then I assume that the summation is nothing more than an unconventional notation for integration.

Comment: You've finished the problem except for the realization that an integral with respect to counting measure is a sum, so your integral is the sum.

Comment: Summing over an uncountable set isn't so unusual, and it isn't meant to be an integral.  If at most countably many terms of the sum are nonzero then it means what you think it does. If uncountably many terms are nonzero then you take the sum to be $\infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you observe, $P(X+Y=0)=\int_{\Bbb R}\mu(\{-y\})\,\nu(dy)$. The function $y\mapsto \mu(\{-y\})$ is non-zero for at most countably many values of $y$; call the set of those values $D$. We then have
$$
\int_{\Bbb R}\mu(\{-y\})\,\nu(dy)=\int_D \mu(\{-y\})\,\nu(dy)=\sum_{z\in D}\int_{\{z\}}\mu(\{-y\})\,\nu(dy)=\sum_{z\in D}\mu(\{-z\})\,\nu(\{z\}).
$$
The sum in question is in fact a sum with only countably many non-zero terms.

Comment: Nice. Yes, this seems to clear it all up. However, book should probably still define what is meant by the sum over such a set.

Comment: Just to clarify, your function from $y\mapsto \mu(\{-y\})$ is nonzero for countably many values because it is a measure related to the distribution, and since a distribution is monotone increasing it can only have countable many places where it's not continuous?

Comment: Yes, because $\mu(\{-y\})=F(-y)-F((-y)-)$, where $F$ is the cdf associated with $\mu$.

Comment: Also, why does the second equality hold?  I get the intuitive idea, but why can I rigorously say that this integral over the countable set D is just the sum of the integral over the individual points?

Answer (score 3):

For non-negative summands $\phi(y)\geq 0$, the uncountable sum is defined as 
$$\sum_{y\in Y} \phi(y)=\sup\left\{ \sum_{y\in F} \phi(y) : F \mbox{ is a finite subset of }Y\right\}.$$

---

In the countable case, Durrett  gives a definition on page 20 just after Theorem 1.4.7.

Comment: Nice generalization. Is it now popular in the existing textbooks ?

Comment: @FardadPouran Good question. If I have time later, I'll flip through a few books to see if I can find this. I didn't find it in any book, to me this is the obvious definition.

Comment: I was given this definition in my undergraduate real analysis class, but in this particular problem it doesn't seem to make any sense to interpret it this way.

Comment: @JT1 "doesn't seem to make any sense" Why not? It captures exactly what you  want. We sum over some countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ without specifying in advance what that set is.

Comment: What I'm saying is that based on my computation the sum and integral notations would be interchangeable in case the problem is correct. I don't see how we can justify replacing the integral in my computation with a sum of this form.

Comment: @JT1 Ah, you are right. The sum and the integral are the same, but it is not so obvious. Let me think about that.